# Save features in personal geodatabase using ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to save the features in the personal geodatabase using ArcGIS JavaScript. from the feature prospective I'm having the geometry of the graphic layer added to the map.

Comment: Use Geo processing service..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not posiblle using only javascript.

You can write a geoprocessing service or a asp.net webservice using arcObjects that writes to the fgb, access that using javascript.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_geoprocessing_with_ArcGIS_Server/002v00000001000000/

Comment: So for every operation we need a Geo Processing service has to write...?

Comment: For saving geometries to a database, you need either need a feature service connected to ArcSDE, or a custom geoprocessing service to save to a file or personal geodatabase, as you requested.

Comment: @Jagadesh Feature services work only with ArcSDE, so your only option is to have a Geoprocessing Service